Same sf cli command works locally but not in Github Action
I have this command in the Github Action workflow sf project deploy validate -x delta/package/package.xml -l RunSpecifiedTests -t randomClassTest
Scenario: I deploy a new Apex class.
I received this error in the pipeline Error (1): No source-backed components present in the package. So I tried to replicate it to see what caused the error in my local environment but it worked. Here are the following steps:

name: Create delta package for new/modified or deleted data

mkdir delta
sfdx sgd:source:delta --to "HEAD" --from "HEAD~1" --output delta/ --generate-delta --source force-app/

Do some check to pull out which Apex class needs to run. This is just a variable in Github.
name: Validate Apex Class

sf project deploy validate -x delta/package/package.xml -l RunSpecifiedTests -t RandomClassTest
This is what inside the delta/package/package.xml. Left side is the folder structure. Right side is what inside the package.xml.

Thank you so muchhhh.

Are you installing the sgd plugin in your github action? That'd be a separate step that you need to do alongside installing sfdx in the first place.

Yes I did @DerekF

Afraid I don't have many additional details. Perhaps you could try to echo the contents of delta/package/package.xml so you can see it in the log of the (github) workflow run. Maybe use actions/upload-artifact@v3 to make the package.xml an artifact (that you could view/inspect for 24 hours before I think github deletes it). Either way, the goal here is to check to see if your package.xml looks right.

actions/checkout may only be fetching a single commit too, making HEAD~1 behave oddly.

Thanks @DerekF for your recommendations. I really appreciate your help. I found out the reason why the error happened. It is because for new apex class, we need to add the meta.xml as well.
I didn't add it -> It failed to check.
I will update the answers.
